# IoT Hub Shared Access Signature in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-iot-hub

How do I create an IoT Hub Shared Access Signature using PowerShell. My code works when using the signature generated in the Azure IoT Explorer. Assume something is wrong with the signature generation:

```
$Uri = "$IotHubName.azure-devices.net/devices/$IotDeviceId"
$Expiry = [string](([DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds())+3600)
$IotHubKeyDecoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IotHubKey)) 
$StringToSign = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Uri) + "`n" + $Expiry
$Hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$Hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($IotHubKeyDecoded)
$Signature = $Hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($StringToSign))
$Signature = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode([Convert]::ToBase64String($Signature))
```

I tried using New-AzIotHubSasToken but getting 'Unauthorized':

```
$SharedAccessSignature = New-AzIotHubSasToken -ResourceGroupName $IotHub.ResourceGroupName -IotHubName $IotHubName -DeviceId $IotDeviceId 
$Headers = @{"Authorization" = $SharedAccessSignature; "Content-Type"="application/json";} 
$Uri = "https://$IotHubName.azure-devices.net/devices/$IotDeviceId/messages/events?api-version=2020-03-13" 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -Method Post -Body $JsonBody
```

Comment: Have you given the [New-AzIotHubSasToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/new-aziothubsastoken?view=azps-5.0.0) cmdlet a try?

Comment: Using New-AzIotHubSasToken is the right way to do this. The reason it didn't work for me was a bug in the PowerShell module. This is due to be fixed with the release of December 8, 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to create a SAS token in that way, but you could use either PowerShell or Azure CLI for that purpose (you must install it first).

Here you have both examples:

```
# PowerShell
New-AzIotHubSasToken -IotHubName "{IoT Hub Name}" -DeviceId "{Device Id}" -ResourceGroupName "{Resource Group Name}"

# Output
SharedAccessSignature sr={IoT Hub Name}.azure-devices.net%2fdevices%2f{Device Id}&sig=iuhiAfagvhgd3QtqjukX8upPuWj%2fuJuYn%2bJgeOe6Uwo%3d&se=1604085022

# Azure CLI
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n {IoT Hub Name} -d {Device Id}

# Output
{
  "sas": "SharedAccessSignature sr={IoT Hub Name}.azure-devices.net%2fdevices%2f{Device Id}&sig=iuhiAfagvhgd3QtqjukX8upPuWj%2fuJuYn%2bJgeOe6Uwo%3d&se=1604085022"
}
```

Remember you must first login and then select the corresponding subscription (in case you have more than one)

```
az login
# Optionally: az account list
az account set --subscription {subscription id}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. The reason it didn't work for me was a bug in the PowerShell module. This is due to be fixed with the release of December 8, 2020.